# Pandas read_csv failing on gzipped file with OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'NU')

Tags: pandas, gzip

I used the code ask below to load the csv.gz file but I got the error

```
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'NU')
```

How can I solve it?
Code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('climat.202010.csv.gz', compression='gzip')
print(data)
```

Or:

```
import gzip
import pandas as pd
filename = 'climat.202010.csv.gz'
with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    data = pd.read_csv(f)
```

Comment: The csv.gz file is downloaded from here:
https://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr/?fond=donnee_libre&prefixe=Txt%2FClimat%2Fclimat&extension=csv.gz&date=202010

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import gzip
with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as fio:
    df = pd.read_csv(fio)
```

Comment: I used the code as your comment. But still get this error 
import gzip

import pandas as pd

filename = 'climat.202010.csv.gz'

with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:

    data = pd.read_csv(f)

Comment: I now suspect your gz file is corrupt? How was it create?

Comment: Just try csv = f.read() within the gzip.open... may need to set compression form.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import gzip
import pandas as pd

with gzip.open(r'C:\Users\MyUser\OneDrive - Company\Data\Wiser\Files\WiserWeeklyReport.csv.gz') as f:
    wiser_report = pd.read_csv(f)

wiser_report.head()
```

If you're still getting an error, it may be the file or the file name. Have you tried taking out the extra period in the file name?

Comment: This looks almost the same as the existing answer. Please add an explanation why you think your answer adds additional value.

Comment: As I said in my comment, the code works for me, so if it throws an error, there are likely other things at play, like the file being corrupt or an issue with the file name. That's not enough?